# Fourier Transform of Distribution Equal to the Distribution Itself

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

We define $T(t)=a\delta^{(n)}+bt^n$ for $a, b$ nonzero complex constants and $n$ a nonnegative integer.  I want to find the combinations of $a, b, n$ such that the fourier transform of $T$ is equal to $T$ itself.  In my mind, the natural first idea is to manually compute the transform.  However, I don't know how to find the transform of $t^n$.  Is there a way to compare the distribution $T$ to its transform without actually computing the transform?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions

Comment: Hmm I see the part you're referring to, but I'm not quite sure why it's true.

Comment: It is a fairly straightforward calculation involving the definition.